# Can 32-bit and 64-bit CentOS 6.4 servers both be AD domain controllers for the same domain?

Tags: centos, samba, architecture, domain, active-directory

If I have two CentOS 6.4 servers, one i386 and the other x86_64, running Samba 4.0.7, will they replicate domain controller data with each other (and from a Windows Server 2003 AD DC) without any special setup?  Can anyone confirm this or a similar setup as having worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the servers architecture should matter as to whether they can participate in a AD domain. Usually the limiting factor is what the schema version is for a given AD domain.

*excerpt from [microsoft.com](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/556086)*

- 13 -> Windows 2000 Server
- 30 -> Windows Server 2003 RTM, Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 1, Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 2
- 31 -> Windows Server 2003 R2
- 44 -> Windows Server 2008 RTM
- 47 -> Windows Server 2008 R2
- 56 -> Windows Server 2012 RTM

I would go over the release notes for the various point releases of Samba 4 and determine if a particular version supports which ever schema your AD domain is currently employing.

- http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_AD_DC_HOWTO

With a normal AD domain you can have multiple nodes participate as slaves, so I would expect the same capabilities from Samba 4.

Comment: I'm not sure why it should matter either--this is admittedly a newb question, but I thought it was safer to ask just in case.  Thanks for the info, I hadn't heard of these two-digit schema versions before.  Do you have direct experience of two different server architectures replicating O.K. though?

Comment: @Kev - yeah I only learned about them recently when I started having to support AD at my day job. We're still in the process of integrating a Samba 4 instances into our AD backend. I know when we set up servers we have to set Windows Server 2012 to be in 2008R2 "mode" so that it can participate as a slave server in our existing AD domain, b/c all the other servers are 2008R2.